# YAML contents different from string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I'm trying to pass in a string from one function to another to be parsed as a regular expression.

Currently, when I do

```
@match = run_rule({ "subjectline" => "What is the weather like in Mumbai?", "rule" => "[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?"})
```

The answer is what I want (matching individual sections of the regular expression).

When I do

```
@match = run_rule({ "subjectline" => "What is the weather like in Mumbai?", "rule" => rule['rule']['rule']})
```

where `rule` is returned from YAML

```
---
rule:
  rule: "[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?"
```

`puts` returns exactly the same thing at the console for

```
puts rule['rule']['rule']
puts "[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?"
```

What's going on?

Comment: You can build a Regexp from string, http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html#M001228

Comment: Just an aside, is it your intention to match `|hat is the weather in foo?`? Because it does. You probably only want `[wW]` as your character class.

Comment: Synopsis of question: Some code, which isn't shown, doesn't work. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works perfectly for me, see:

```
irb(main):079:0> yaml = <<EOI
irb(main):080:0" ---
irb(main):081:0" rule:
irb(main):082:0"   rule: "[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?"
irb(main):083:0" EOI
=> "---\nrule:\n  rule: \"[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?\"\n"
irb(main):084:0> rule = YAML.load(yaml)
=> {"rule"=>{"rule"=>"[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?"}}
irb(main):085:0> args = { "subjectline" => "What is the weather like in Mumbai?", "rule" => rule['rule']['rule']}
=> {"subjectline"=>"What is the weather like in Mumbai?", "rule"=>"[w|W]hat is the weather( like)? in ([^?]+)?"}
irb(main):086:0> args['subjectline'].match args['rule']
=> #<MatchData "What is the weather like in Mumbai" 1:" like" 2:"Mumbai">
```

Something else is going on that you're not showing us.

Comment: You were right. It turns out I was confusing @match with its contents. It was working all along.